# How to flip bits in one operation with c#?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bit

I'm storing flags in an integer and I would like to flip specific bits in certain conditions.

**Condition 1**

```
if bit 3 is true then
   set bit 3 to false
   set bit 2 to true
end if
```

**Condition 2**

```
if bit 5 is true then
   set bit 5 to false
   set bit 4 to true
end if
```

All the others bits should remain unchanged.

Condition 1 and condition 2 are independent.

**Scenario**

```cs
int input_01 = 0b_10101010_10_10_1  // condition 1 and condition 2
int input_02 = 0b_10101010_00_10_1  // condition 1
int input_03 = 0b_10101010_10_00_1  // condition 2
int input_04 = 0b_10101010_01_01_1  // nothing

// apply solution on inputs above to get expected below
// it could be 1 or 2 operations max

int expected_01 = 0b_10101010_01_01_1
int expected_02 = 0b_10101010_00_01_1
int expected_03 = 0b_10101010_01_00_1
int expected_04 = 0b_10101010_01_01_1
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators

Comment: Did you consider Flag-Enum ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum#enumeration-types-as-bit-flags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following function:

```cs
int ShiftOneBit(int value, int bit)
{
    return (value & ~bit) | ((value & bit) >> 1);
}
```

Then use it like this

```cs
x = ShiftOneBit(x, 0b100);
x = ShiftOneBit(x, 0b10000);
```

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kgiZs1)